# How to make collisions with rects in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision, rect

I'm making my first game in pygame for a school project, and I need to make the players stand in platforms. I'm trying to make collisions using rects, but it isn't working. I've seen a lot of tutorials, but I don't understand what is wrong with my code.

I tried to make a rect in both the players and in the platform, but the collision doesn't work. (I put "print" inside the collision block just to check if it was working).

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()

playerwaterimg = pg.image.load("waterboy.png")
playerfireimg = pg.image.load("firegirl.png")
paredeimg = pg.image.load("pedra.jpg")


playerwater = pg.transform.scale(playerwaterimg, (60, 85))
playerfire = pg.transform.scale(playerfireimg, (75, 80))
parede1 = pg.transform.scale(paredeimg, (1366, 30))
parede2 = pg.transform.scale(paredeimg, (30, 768))
parede3 = pg.transform.scale(paredeimg, (30, 768))
parede4 = pg.transform.scale(paredeimg, (1366, 30))
parede5 = pg.transform.scale(paredeimg, (1000, 30))

playerwaterloc = [50, 738 - 60]
playerfireloc = [100, 738 - 75]


rectwater = playerwater.get_rect()
rectfire = playerfire.get_rect()
rectparede5 = parede5.get_rect(topleft = (0, 540))
rectwater.topleft = (playerwaterloc[0], playerwaterloc[1])
rectfire.topleft = (playerfireloc[0], playerfireloc[1])
rectparede5.topleft = (0, 540)


ecratam = (1366, 768)
fundoimagem = pg.image.load("background.jpg")
fundo = pg.transform.scale(fundoimagem, (ecratam[0], ecratam[1]))
ecra = pg.display.set_mode((ecratam[0], ecratam[1]), pg.FULLSCREEN)
clock = pg.time.Clock()

saltarfire = False
saltarwater = False
saltonumfire = 10
saltonumwater = 10


while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    for evento in pg.event.get():
        if evento.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit()
            exit()

    ecra.blit(fundo, (0, 0))

    ecra.blit(playerwater, (playerwaterloc[0], playerwaterloc[1]))
    ecra.blit(playerfire, (playerfireloc[0], playerfireloc[1]))


    ecra.blit(parede1, (0, 738))
    ecra.blit(parede2, (0, 0))
    ecra.blit(parede3, (1336, 0))
    ecra.blit(parede4, (0, 0))
    ecra.blit(parede5, (0, 540))
    
    
    teclas = pg.key.get_pressed()
    
    if teclas[pg.K_LEFT]:
        playerfireloc[0] -= 3

    if teclas[pg.K_RIGHT]:
        playerfireloc[0] += 3

    if not(saltarfire):
        
        if teclas[pg.K_UP]:
            saltarfire = True

        if teclas[pg.K_DOWN]:
            playerfireloc[1] += 3
    
    else:

        if saltonumfire >= -10:
            playerfireloc[1] -= (saltonumfire * abs(saltonumfire)) * 0.3
            saltonumfire -= 0.5
        else:
            saltonumfire = 10
            saltarfire = False



    if teclas[pg.K_a]:
        playerwaterloc[0] -= 3

    if teclas[pg.K_d]:
        playerwaterloc[0] += 3

    if not(saltarwater):
        
        if teclas[pg.K_w]:
            saltarwater = True

        if teclas[pg.K_s]:
            playerwaterloc[1] += 3
    
    else:

        if saltonumwater >= -10:
            playerwaterloc[1] -= (saltonumwater * abs(saltonumwater)) * 0.3
            saltonumwater -= 0.5
        else:
            saltonumwater = 10
            saltarwater = False



    if playerfireloc[1] > ecratam[1] - playerfire.get_height() - parede1.get_height():
        playerfireloc[1] = ecratam[1] - playerfire.get_height() - parede1.get_height()

    if playerwaterloc[1] > ecratam[1] - playerwater.get_height() - parede1.get_height():
        playerwaterloc[1] = ecratam[1] - playerwater.get_height() - parede1.get_height()

    if playerfireloc[1] < parede4.get_height():
        playerfireloc[1] = parede4.get_height()

    if playerwaterloc[1] < parede4.get_height():
        playerwaterloc[1] = parede4.get_height()

    if playerfireloc[0] < parede2.get_width():
        playerfireloc[0] = parede2.get_width()

    if playerwaterloc[0] < parede2.get_width():
        playerwaterloc[0] = parede2.get_width()

    if playerfireloc[0] > ecratam[0] - playerfire.get_width() - parede3.get_width():
        playerfireloc[0] = ecratam[0] - playerfire.get_width() - parede3.get_width()

    if playerwaterloc[0] > ecratam[0] - playerwater.get_width() - parede3.get_width():
        playerwaterloc[0] = ecratam[0] - playerwater.get_width() - parede3.get_width()

    

    if rectwater.colliderect(rectparede5):
        print("Collision")



    pg.display.update()
```